# Unable to shutdown,reboot,hibernate and suspend from desktop in ubuntu 14.04.2 server with lxde

Tags: suspend, shutdown, hibernate, lxde

no problem if I am using CLI on terminal to shutdown, hibernate and reboot.

But the problem is when I try to perform shutdown from GUI it shows

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Operation not permitted
```

I've tried this

https://superuser.com/questions/821976/unable-to-shut-down-from-desktop

but still doesn't works.